# Rails static data set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, activerecord

What is the best way to handle a static data set (non-dynamic)?

For instance, let's say you have a model that has a set of 10 different instances, each of which is unique, but none of which will ever change throughout the lifetime of your application. It seems overkill to create an activerecord model and store this data in the database, but it seems ugly to create a generic class and store this data in the code.

What is accepted as a best practice?

---

**Example:**

You have a **Rate** and a **User**. A User can have a level from 1-10, when the level changes, the rate changes. The rate might have other information, so simply storing it as an attribute on the User might be more trouble than it's worth. Would it make sense to tie it to a Rate or to create it as a method on the User like this:

```
def rate
  case self.level
  when 1:
    { value: "foo", something: "bar", else: "baz" }
  when 2:
    # etc
  end
end
```

It seems that neither of the solutions are ideal, but I'm not sure if there is something else ideal that could happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store this information in a YAML file. You could use the [RailsConfig gem](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config) and create a YAML file like

```
level:
  1:
    some: value
    another: value
  2:
    some: second value
    another: second value
```

And then access it with

```
rate = 2
val = Settings.level[rate.to_s].some
```

(I'm not completely sure with numbers as keys in YAML, maybe you have to escape them)

Answer (score 0):

I use constants in this cases: constants do not change after the declaration, but the declaration can be dynamic:

```
OS =
  case RUBY_PLATFORM
  when /linux/   then :linux
  when /osx/     then :osx
  when /windows/ then :windows
  else                :unknown
```

Performance should be better when using constants for static values, because they should be memoized (and because staticity should be their purpose, so probably Ruby implementations trust about it; I read something about JRuby and constants implementation, I'll post it if I'll find. **EDIT** I found it: http://blog.headius.com/2012/09/avoiding-hash-lookups-in-ruby.html).